# GKScore suddenly goes wrong in Xcode 3.2.5, how can I do?

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I have a small game in app store, use game kit's Leaderboard. Code just from the Xcode document.

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category {

    if (!auth_ok) 
     return;
    Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKScore"));
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[gcClass alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
     else {
      NSLog(@"reportScore ok!");
     }

   }];
}
```

It never go wrong. But today I use Xcode 3.2.5 build this project. And change some other code,and I find now GKScore report score is wrong. I call reportScore message like this:

```
int winCount=15;
[gameView reportScore:winCount forCategory:@"memory.iphone.wincount"];
```

and result is value=761228871165046176.like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just work rightnow, automately...